# Array to sort worlds by word class in a text

Tags: javascript

How can I make a script that sorts words in a text field by word class. Verb and adjectives etc.

```js
array()
```

Comment: btw, it is a function call with the name `array`.

Comment: Post some code that you've tried. What is working, what is not working. Then people can understand the problem you're facing and try to help you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of text mining library to do this and more specifically what you want to do it's called *tokenization*:

Each word in a string is categorized as a lexical token with a syntactical role e.g verb, pronoun etc.

See [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) and [text mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining) for more info.

There is a Javascript library called [RiTaJS](http://rednoise.org/rita/index.php) which gives you the ability to tokenize a string into parts of speech.

From the [site](http://rednoise.org/rita/tutorial/analyzing.php#POS)

> You can use `RiTa.getPosTags` to analyze the part-of-speech (or POS) for you.

```
RiTa.getPosTags("I am hungry");
```

> The outcome would be: `["prp", "vbp", "jj"]`

To see what these tokens mean, check the [reference](http://rednoise.org/rita/reference/PennTags.html)

Comment: Thanks ill edit the software a little bit. So it suits the Swedish language

Comment: Glad to be of help and good luck with it! RiTaJS uses English grammar only rules to tag the words so your results with Swedish will probably be from little to waaayyy off :) but go ahead and try it. You can also ask the developers if there's anything similar for Swedish or something more generic.

Comment: The output from `RiTa.getPosTags("I am hungry")` is actually ["prp", "vbp", "jj"]

Comment: @rednoyz you are correct! In fact it's correct even at the reference page. I've edited the answer with the correct output ;)